# Como executar comandos do shell na inicialização do debian?

Tags: linux, script, shell, inicialização

Preciso que ao ligar meu *raspberry pi 3* para que ele execute os seguintes scripts:

```
$cd ~/Desktop
$source ~/.profile
$workon cv
$python raspberry.py
```

somente isso, dai ele ja vai rodar meu programa diretamente.

Comment: Você tem alguma interface gráfica instalada ??

Comment: tenho sim, é o raspbian

Answer (score 3):

Siga os passos:

1. Crie um arquivo para seu script e escreva os comandos nele.

   ```
   $ sudo nano /etc/init.d/SEUSCRIPT
   ```

   - Exemplo:

     ```
     #!/bin/bash 
     echo "Script de exemplo"
     ```
2. Salve e saia: `CTRL`+ `X`, `Y`, `ENTER`
3. De permissão para ser executável

   ```
   $ sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/SEUSCRIPT
   ```
4. Registra o script para ser executado na inicialização

   ```
   $ sudo update-rc.d superscript defaults
   ```

> Obs: *SEUSCRIPT* é o nome do arquivo que você deseja criar

---

Caso deseja iniciar quando você inicializa no ambiente `LXDE` faça:

1. Navegue até:

   ```
   ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi
   ```
2. Abra o arquivo `autostart`

   ```
   $ sudo nano autostart
   ```
3. Adicione em nova linha cada comando
4. Salve e saia: `CTRL`+ `X`, `Y`, `ENTER`
5. Reinicie o sistema.

> Para mais informações [raspberrypi stackexchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up)

Comment: eu quero iniciar assim que der boot no sistema. Voce pode me mostrar como é a sintaxe do script? Não trabalho com linux. é so eu escrever os meus comandos num script.sh ? vai o $ na frente ou só escrevo normal.

Comment: Sim vou editar colocar um exemplo de *Script*

Comment: tinha visto que tem que usar o #!/bin/sh no raspberry, você tem ideia se o bash funciona normal? Se eu optar pelo sh mudo mais alguma coisa do que você me tinha explicado?

Comment: `#!/bin/sh` é apenas um link para `#!/bin/bash`